# Masonry: eventie.bind doesn't click on an img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

[Example of what I'm trying to do with Masonry.](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html) (The "layout" method)

The problem is within eventie.bind().

```
    classie.toggle( event.target, 'gigante' );
```

I have images inside the div. The event fires if I click on the image but nothing happens. It only works if I click inside the padding of the div.

I believe `event.target` is selecting the img and toggling the class for the image when I really want it to target the div wrapped around the img and toggle the div's class. How do I get it to select the div when I click on the img inside the div?

## Example

```
    < div class="item" >
      < img src="some_img" />
    < /div >
```

click on image to get...

```
    < div class="item gigante" >
      < img src="some_img" />
    < /div >
```

using jQuery / eventie.bind() / `classie.toggle(event.target, 'gigante');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('img').bind('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('gigante');
});

img {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: I went with something closer to this answer but I think both answers should work. Essentially they're the same. Although, now I'm not using `eventie.bind` but I think that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some jQuery that might help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

;(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("div img").click(function(){

            var parent = $(this).parent();            
            parent.toggleClass('gigante');

            var cls = parent.attr('class');
            console.log('class: ' + cls);            

        });

    });

})(jQuery);

</script>

<div>

    <div class="item">
        <img src="[your image path goes here]" />
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you included classie.js script in your page?

As said here : http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html, classie is not included with masonry.

You can find it here : https://github.com/desandro/classie